# Re-direct External .php requests to extension-less URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I manage several sites that used to be written in ColdFusion but now are in PHP.  The goals of my HTACCESS file for each of these sites are the following:

1. Always resolve the naked domain to a www.domain.com
2. Re-direct any external .CFM file to a .PHP, as long as the file exists
3. Serve all .PHP requests as extensionless URL's, with or without QUERY STRINGS

For the most part, my HTACCESS rules work.  The only issue I'm having are external .php request in search engines not resolving to extension-less URL's.  Here's HTACCESS file:

```
#Main Page
DirectoryIndex index.php
AddDefaultCharset OFF
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Never Use the naked domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Never Use the naked domain and Remove PHP extension
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RedirectMatch 301 /([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)\.cfm((\?.*)|())$ http://www.domain.com/$1$2
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)((\?.*)|())$ http://www.domain.com/$1.php$2 [L]

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Most of the sites I'm dealing with don't have SSL or HTTPS requests.  As I mentioned these rules have worked except for resolving .php requests to extension-less URL's.  Also, my HTACCESS file is placed in my web root.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your .htaccess like this:

```
#Main Page
DirectoryIndex index.php
AddDefaultCharset OFF
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Never Use the naked domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301,NE]

# Never Use the naked domain and Remove PHP extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.(php|cfm)[\s?] [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.(cfm|php)$ /$1 [R=301,L,NE]

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This set of directives:

```
# Never Use the naked domain and Remove PHP extension
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RedirectMatch 301 /([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)\.cfm((\?.*)|())$ http://www.domain.com/$1$2
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)((\?.*)|())$ http://www.domain.com/$1.php$2 [L]
```

Has some problems. The rewrite condition doesn't apply to a `RedirectMatch`, which isn't even part of mod_rewrite. It's part of mod_alias and gets applied at a different part of the request processing pipeline.
It should probably look something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(cfm|php)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

You don't need to filter by a condition of HTTP_HOST.

Comment: So, should I use THE_REQUEST for my RewriteCond?